# Browser new tab opens without loading data in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, browser

I am currently experiencing an issue with my Flutter web app. My intention is to open my **result** widget in a new tab of the browser, which I have accomplished successfully using the following code:

```
html.window.open('/#${Result.routeName}', "_blank");
```

However, I am encountering a problem where the data on this page fails to load. I have attempted various approaches, such as hardcoding the data, utilising local storage, and even refreshing the page, but none of them have proven effective. Interestingly, when I open the tab in the same window using the following code:

```
html.window.open('/#${Result.routeName}', "_self");
```

Everything functions flawlessly. I am uncertain whether I am overlooking a specific aspect of browser functionality or if there is an error in my implementation. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.